# Как сохранить query.id в localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Здраствуйте, это мой по счёту 2 или 3 вопрос о моей проблеме с id в localStorage, последнее что осталось решить чтобы на 90% закончить проект. Я не смог найти информацию о решении, так как я пишу на Next.js и на нём localStorage как то странно работает. Проблема:

На этой главной странице я id должен сохранить в localStorage

```
import { useState, useEffect, use } from 'react';
import styles  from '../Card/Card.module.css'
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function Card() {
    

    
  const {query} = useRouter()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    payKey.setData(query.id);
  }, [query.id])



  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem('id',payKey.data)
    console.log(localStorage)
  })


    const {query} = useRouter()
    const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
      fetch(`https://example.com/pay/type/`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => setInfo(result))
      },[])

    return (
     <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
         {   info.map((value)=>{
              
          return(
            <Link href={`payment`} key={value.id}>
            <div  className={styles.paytype}>
                <div className={styles.photo}>
                  <img src={value.image} alt="image"/>
                  <span>{value.name}</span>
                </div>
                <div><p>{value.text}</p></div>
            </div>
            </Link>
             )

            })
         }
      </div>
     </>
    );
  }
  
  export default Card;
```

И вызвать в другой странице этот id  из localStorage и вставить в value

```
<input type="hidden" name="ClientId" value={''} />
```

Куда сохраняется id и откуда я импортировал payKey:

```
class Store {
  #data = "";
  constructor(begin) {
    this.#data = begin || "";
  }

  setData(data) {
    this.#data = data;
  }

  get data() {
    return this.#data;
  }
}

const payKey = new Store();
export { payKey };
```

Comment: А где обращение к `localStorage`?

Comment: Здраствуйте, я удалил код так как он был не полным, теперь добавил, можете посмотреть @EzioMercer

Comment: Что у вас в `payKey.data`?

Comment: Там расположен ```id``` который я беру с помощью ```query``` из ```useRouter```, то есть ```id``` пользователя @EzioMercer

Comment: `data` - это объект?

Comment: да, это объект @EzioMercer

Comment: Тогда это вы работаете с `localStorage` странно, а не `Next.js` :) Почитайте про его [аргументы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#parameters) вам будет полезно. А так вам надо использовать `JSON.stringify(payKey.data)`, а при чтении `JSON.parse` надо будет использовать

Comment: Я вам вот тут показывал, как можно организовать [хранение данных в localStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480839/1481776#1481776)

Comment: @SwaD Если `data` - это объект, то его надо привести к строке и только потом записывать в `localStorage`

Comment: @EzioMercer У задающего data это некий ID толи транзакции, то ли плательщика. Т.е. это либо строка, либо число. [Вот тут начало этой истории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480297/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: @SwaD, я не понял как записать значение в localStorage  внутри хранилища, я в комментах спросил вы ответить забыли

Comment: Зайдите [вот сюда](https://codesandbox.io/s/router-ggw6w5?file=/src/pay.js) и посмотрите, как сделано. В примере все работает. Данные сохраняются и отображаются

Comment: @SwaD Ладно, вам виднее, раз так давно с ним работаете. Не буду вам мешать :) Просто на мой вопрос объект ли `data` автор ответил положительно, вот я подумал что неправильно работает с `localStorage`

Comment: @EzioMercer Конечно, уже может что и поменялось. А вот помощь мне как раз не повредит! :) Может я чего не так говорю или рассказываю... Возможно, сказанное то же самое, но другими словами будет лучше пониматься.

Comment: @SwaD Автору просто надо как и вы сделать пример в песочнице и показать нам, что там не работает. Просто тут запрещено использовать `localStorage`, потому не получится тут сделать воспроизводимый пример. Надеюсь автор прислушается :)

Comment: Я тут понял что свойство ```localStorage``` определено для ```window``` объекта и недоступно при использовании рендеринга на стороне сервера с Next.js.

Comment: Я попытаюсь сделать пример  и дам вам знать @EzioMercer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема в том, что твой `Store` никак не участвует в жизненном цикле реакт-компонента, поэтому он и не вызывает перерендер компонента, а значит и `useEffect`, в котором ты сохраняешь `id` в `localStorage`, не отрабатывает

Думаю, чтобы решить проблему, достаточно сделать так:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState, useEffect, use } from 'react';

import styles from '../Card/Card.module.css'

function Card() {
  const { query } = useRouter();

  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    payKey.setData(query.id);

    localStorage.setItem('id',payKey.data);
    console.log(localStorage);
  }, [query.id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://example.com/pay/type/`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => setInfo(result))
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
  
export default Card;
```